# How can I configure Android studio to add new line at end of file?

Tags: android, git, newline, code-formatting

I use Android Studio and when I commit to a repo on GitHub and view git diff I see a red marker at end of line for few files with a warning 'No newline at end of file'. How can I configure Android Studio to ensure that it does add a newline at file of file for every file. Thank you.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Android Studio to automatically add a new line at the end of a file.

`File | Settings...` menu, then `Editor` under `IDE Settings`, then check the `Ensure line feed at file end on Save` option box.

This will only take effect on freshly edited files after the setting has been enabled.

---

#### UPDATE

On newer versions of Android Studio, the preference location has changed to

`File > Preferences > Editor > General > Ensure line feed at file end on Save`

Comment: It is `File → Settings → ..`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for justification of _why_ to include a newline at the end of a file but couldn't find it. Why do we do that and why does Github call it out? Is it something with *nix? Edit: Sorry [here's the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline) I'm looking for

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot He's probably referring to Mac. Though on Mac it would be `Android Studio > Preferences > ...`

Comment: Option label now is `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`. Also, for it to work properly, you have to uncheck `Keep trailing spaces on caret line`.

Answer (score 18):

In the latest Android Studio (2.3.3), the setting has moved.

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Ensure line feed at file end on Save

Comment: In Android Studio 3.5

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Ensure line feed at file end on Save`

Answer (score 9):

[image]

On Android Studio Bumblbee open **Preferences** -> **General** -> enable option "**Ensure every saved file ends with a line break**"

Answer (score 0):

The previous changes for Android Studio ([53630 - 
52407](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/53630/) and  [54132 - 52407: should add a newline at the end of autogenerated xml files](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/54132/)) seem to suggest there is no *global* setting to add a newline for *every* file.

It may have changed depending on the Android Studio you are using (eclipse-based or the more recent [IntellJ IDEA-based](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/)), but you can check the **[formatters](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html)** associated with the different types of files: they usually have that option "add newline at the end of a (certain type of) file".